# Can't seems to store more than 1 user input name and password inside my list

Tags: c#

I'm currently doing a username and password input list. But I'm having issue on storing all the input in the list. Whenever I create a new input, it will automatically replace the first input.

This is the main class

```cs
public static Administrator admin = new Administrator("", "", "", "");
public static Staff staff = new Staff("", "", "", "");
public static User_Management userm = new User_Management();
public static Categories cat = new Categories("");
public static Categories_Management catm = new Categories_Management();
public static Product prod = new Product("", "", "", cat, "");
public static Products_Management prodm = new Products_Management();

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<User_Management> UserList = new List<User_Management>();
    bool Start = false;

    while (!Start)
    {
        bool stop = false;

        while (!stop)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Are you registered? Yes||No");
            string yesno = Console.ReadLine();
            if (yesno.Equals("No", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ///register part
                //Administrator Cadmin = new Administrator("", "", "", "");
                admin.CreateUser();
                userm.AddUser(admin);
                //Adminlist.Add(admin);

                /*for (int i = 0; i < userm.users.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("User ID: {0}", userm.users[i].name);
                    Console.WriteLine("Password: {0}", userm.users[i].CPassword);

                }*/

                Console.WriteLine("\nAdministrator account created!");
                Console.ReadLine();

                ///login part
                Console.WriteLine("Login as? Admin||Staff");
                string login = Console.ReadLine();

                if (login.Equals("Admin", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    //Administrator Ladmin = new Administrator("", "", "", "");
                    admin.LoginUser();
                    userm.Match();

                    foreach (User u in userm.users)
                    {
                        if (admin.Name == admin.LName && admin.Password == admin.LPassword)
                        {
                            stop = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            stop = false;
                        }
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();
```

Comment: "[How do debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Comment: If your program isn't doing what you expect, then that means as you step through the debugger there will eventually be a specific operation which isn't producing the result you expect.  Which specific operation is that in your code?  What are the runtime values when that happens?  What was the result of that operation?  What result did you expect?  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you initialize your properties every time you access them. A way to initialize them only once might look like this for example. But there are other ways as well.

```
public static User_Management userm { get; } = new User_Management();
```